# Java 8 | type Map.Entry does not define getValue(LinkedHashMap<String,House>)

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a class named `Street` and it has property of type `House` and it has property of type `Room`.

```
class Street{
   private House house;
   // getters & setters
}
```

`House` class has a property `Room`:

```
class House {
   private Room room;
   // getters & setters
}
```

`Room` class has a property roomCapacity:

```
class Room {
   private double roomCapacity;
   // getters & setters
}
```

I want to sort `Street` HashMap of `House` HashMap on the base of `Room` class property named roomCapacity.

Means, every street should have sorted house by room capacity.

```
Map<Street, Map<Long, House>> streetMapFromDB = map;
Map<Street, Map<Long, House>> streetMap =null;
Comparator<Room> orderByRoomCapacity = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Room::getRoomCapacity, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder())));
streetMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(streetMapFromDB.values().stream().map(
                m -> m.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, House> comparingByValue(orderByRoomCapacity ))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

But I am getting error: `type Map.Entry does not define getValue(LinkedHashMap<String,House>)`

**Data Format:**

```
//streetMap={Street={House={RoomCapacity}},{House={RoomCapacity}}}
streetMapFromDB={1={11={4}),2={12={7}}}
```

Comment: Can you provide how the `streetMap` is formed. What is the key and the value. Is your desire to sort by the value. i.e. `Map<Long, House>`

Comment: @Klaus //streetMap={Street={House={RoomCapacity},House={RoomCapacity}}

Comment: what is the type of `streetMapFromDB`?

Comment: @Naman Map<Street, Map<Long, House>>

Comment: then why do you expect `Comparator<Room> orderByRoomCapacity` to be inferred as `Comparator<Map.Entry<Long, House>>`?

Comment: @Naman yes,I am expecting Comparator<House> this is for Map<Long, House> which is inside of Street Map because I want to sort inner map by roomCapacity.

Comment: code does sorting well but unable to return Map<Street, Map<Long, House>>.

Comment: @tyb9900 What is the reason in storing **one single** house in a `Street` object? Isn't it possible to have multiple houses in same street? Same for question for `House` and `Room`.

Comment: You create a `Stream<Map<…>>` and hence, can’t apply a collector which expects a `Stream<Map.Entry<…>>`. Besides that, there is no point in collecting to a `LinkedHashMap` in the `map` operation, when you’re going to collect to an unspecified map type in the outer operation.